# Show that maximum modulus of complex function assumes on saddle point.

Tags: complex-analysis

> (a) Find the saddle points  $z_1, z_2$ of $$f(z) = \frac{(z-1)^2(z+1)}{z^2}$$
>
> (b) Show that $$|f(z_i)|=\max_{|z|=|z_i|} |f(z)|, i = 1, 2$$
>
> (c) Find lines through $z_i$ on which $|f|$ has a relative maximum or a
>   relative minimum at $z_i$.

This is the question I'm working on. I've shown that $z = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{7}i}{2}$ are the saddle points $z_1$ and $z_2$. And I tried using maximum modulus theorem to solve (b), but I realized that maximum modulus theorem only tells you that analytic function's maximum lies on the border, but there's no clue after that, regarding where exactly along the border will be the maximum point. Is there something special about saddle point that as this (b) question states, saddle points are indeed critical points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a true answer, but it may help to understand what is "under the hood". Here is the graphical representation of function

$$Z=\phi(X,Y)=|f(z)| \ \ \text{where} \ \ z=X+iY.$$

(caution : $Z$ represents the 3rd component in this $\mathbb{R}^3$ representation ; different from $z$ !) with some of its level lines.

[image]

One sees

- the two roots $\zeta_1:=-1$ (simple root) represented by a kind of cone, whereas root $\zeta_2:=1$ (double root) is represented by a kind of paraboloid.
- the pole $\zeta_3=0$ which "induces" the central peak (truncated on the figure).

The $(X,Y)$ coordinates of the saddle points of the surface have been represented by little stars.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you have any suggestions on how to move forward though? I'm stuck still with this problem and can't figure out what could I try.